# Why are there mistakes in the calculating (Eclipse) in my Android Application?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have been working on an Android app, which calculates various actions with complex numbers. I had several errors, but the stackoverflow community has been very helpful and i do realize that my style needs improving (naming things). The PROBLEM however is that the program is making calculation mistakes, ive triple checked all the code but for some reason it doesn't calculate things correctly (ie 2+2 is not 4) and the logcat shows no errors. I've also tried moving the part that outputs the answer to various places, but it still makes mistakes. This is my code:

```
    package complex.OliverV;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.RadioButton;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    public class ComplexNumbersActivity extends Activity {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
Button Check;
RadioButton plus, minus, multiply, div;
EditText X1,X2,Y1,Y2;
TextView Ans;
int sign;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Check = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Check);
    plus = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.plus);
    minus = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.minus);
    multiply = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.multiply);
    div = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.div);
    Ans = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Ans);
    X1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.X1);
    X2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.X2);
    Y1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.Y1);
    Y2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.Y2);
    plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            sign=1;
        }


    });
    minus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            sign=2;
        }


    });
    multiply.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            sign=3;
        }


    });
    div.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            sign=4;
        }


    });
    Check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String xs=X1.getText().toString();
            String xss=X2.getText().toString();
            String ys=Y1.getText().toString();
            String yss=Y2.getText().toString();
            double x3, y3;
            if(!xs.equals("") && !xss.equals("") && !ys.equals("") && !yss.equals("")&& xs != null && xss != null && ys != null && yss != null)
            {
            double x1=Double.parseDouble(xs);
            double x2=Double.parseDouble(xss);
            double y1=Double.parseDouble(ys);
            double y2=Double.parseDouble(yss);
            switch(sign)
            {
            case(1):
            {
                x3=(x1+x2);
                y3=(y1+y2);
                Ans.setText("x = "+x3+"y = "+y3);
            }
            case(2):
            {
                x3=(x1-x2);
                y3=(y1-y2);
                Ans.setText("x = "+x3+"y = "+y3);
            }
            case(3):
            {
                x3=((x1*x2) - (y1*y2));
                y3=((x2*y1) + (x1*y2));
                Ans.setText("x = "+x3+"y = "+y3);
            }
            case(4):
            {
                if(x2!=0 && y2!=0)
                {
                x3 = ((x1 * x2) + (y1 * y2)) / ((x2 * x2) + (y2 * y2));
                y3 = ((x2 * y1) - (x1 * y2)) / ((x2 * x2) + (y2 * y2));
                Ans.setText("x = "+x3+"y = "+y3);
                }
                else
                {
                    Ans.setText("Enter valid numbers!");
                }
            }

        }
        }
            else
            {
                Ans.setText("Enter valid numbers!");
            }
        }
    });
}       
}
```

Comment: i get 1, i will rename them if all else fails and i do realize that its probably come back to bite me in the ass.

Comment: Are you sure that your plus button really has the id `R.id.plus` and that your divide button has `R.id.div` and that they aren't switched?

Comment: yep all of them are correctly assigned, that was the first place i looked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing `break;` statements in your `switch`. Add them at the end of every `case`. Also the `{}` are unnecessary for each `case`.

Comment: i feel like  jumping from a window,, when it's something that obvious. thanks a million :))